# if else statement concurrency with fork()

Tags: c, if-statement, process, fork, simultaneous-calls

While reading through some articles about fork() in C, I saw this example (code below) which I couldn't understand:

Understanding problem:
We only run "if" or "else" and not both. But since the child and parent processes run "simultaneoustly", in this example we see that we went through "if" and "else" both!
Eventhough it's similtaneous, it isn't in reality, it depends on which one of the processes will get the CPU first (right?).

What makes everything "weirder" is that we might first go through the "else" and then through the "if". How is this possible ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void forkexample()
{
    // child process because return value zero
    if (fork() == 0)
        printf("Hello from Child!\n");
  
    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    else
        printf("Hello from Parent!\n");
}
int main()
{
    forkexample();
    return 0;
}
```

Possible Outputs are:

Hello from Child!

Hello from Parent!

(or)

Hello from Parent!

Hello from Child!

Comment: *it depends on which one of the processes will get the CPU first*  **THE** CPU?  There can be more than one...

Comment: the posted code has a major flaw.   The call to `fork()` has a third return, -1 when an error occurs.  In the current code the error return will output: "Hello from Parent!\n"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the `fork` function actually returns twice: once to the parent with the child's pid and once to the child with 0.

At that point you have two independent processes running the same code and printing to the same terminal.  And since you have two processes, the kernel is free to schedule them in any way it sees fit, meaning the output of either process can appear in any order.

Comment: Ouh okay, that means the **WHOLE** code will be ran by Parent-Process and output **Hello from Parent!** And independently the Child Process will run and output **Hello from Child!"

Comment: @WassimJaoui Correct

Comment: But this will only happen if we have created a child using fork(), right ? But in this case we didn't !? Or does the fork() == 0 also created a child ?!? Or there's a part of the code missing ?

Comment: @WassimJaoui The `fork` call by definition creates a child process.  In the parent, `fork() == 0` will evaluate to false while in the child it will evaluate to true.

Comment: but when did we call **fork** ?

Comment: @WassimJaoui when the computer runs the line with `fork()` it calls fork. I hope this is not news. Just like when the computer runs the line with `printf("hi")` it calls printf.

Comment: @user253751 that's of course not new, I just was a bit confused. So if I got it right we created the cild in: if (fork() == 0), right ?

Comment: @WassimJaoui Yes, the execution of that line is like: 1. call fork(), 2. look at its return value, 3. see if it was equal to 0. 4. go to 'if' or 'else' block. So after step 1 there are two processes and step 2/3/4 run separately in each process.

Answer (score 2):

`fork` is a system call, which does following (in abstraction, actual implementation likely to differ on the modern systems):

- Creates a copy of the process image in memory and sets it up as a process with it's own PID
- In one image (the child) returns 0
- In second image (the parent) returns the PID of the new process
- Schedules execution of both images as usual

As a result, on the multi-core system, both parent and a child are going to be executing independently, and absent other synchronization, in no way related to each other.

And if you observe the output of those two processes, you will find out that output from those can come in any shape or form - you can have output from the parent preceding output from the child, succeeding it or being interleaved with it - it is unpredictable what you will end up seeing.